Parallel computing is disabled in Quanteda CRAN version. How can I enable Parallel computing in M3 Mac OS X
I am having problem with enablingh quanteda's parallel computing in R on M3 Macbook. In GitHub, the readme says

Windows or macOS users do not have to install TBB or any other packages to enable parallel computing when installing quanteda from CRAN.

When I activate the  CRAN version of the package I get this verbose below, how can I enable Parallel computing ARM based Macbooks
library(quanteda)
Package version: 4.0.2
Unicode version: 14.0
ICU version: 71.1
Parallel computing: disabled
See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

I have also installed needed softwares to activate parallel computing,  but I am getting the same verbose.
I would like to enable the parallel computing feature of R Quanteda package

Have you tried everything in the install gude?

The guide and GitHub readme there is no need to install anything if you install package from CRAN.https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda

This page explains how to install on Mac http://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/parallelisation.html

I installed Xcode, Homebrew, TBB, Gfortran but there is no progress. I am still getting same verbose. I have raised the issue in Github repo too.

I'm still having this issue. I'm curious if there was ever a fix identified? Same OS, same version of quanteda.
